# curious side effect in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I dont understand what makes the different cases to work or not.
I would have expected them to work all obviously.

- funs2 and funs4 only close over the last value of n for some reason : they behave as if n was always 5.
- funs3 captures each element of the sequence : it behaves as if n enumerated from 1 to 5, and mapped for each n to a different function, which will approximate the dataset differently (with increasing degree of freedom)

The script should be runnable directly in R with no dependance beside plyr.

Any clue ?

```
library(plyr)
f      <- function (x) { sin(2*pi*x) }
fnoisy <- function (x) {f(x) + 0.3*rnorm(1)}

x10 <- runif(10)
y10 <- aaply(x10,1,fnoisy)

curve(f,0,1,col="blue", ylim=c(-1.5,1.5))
points(x10, y10, col="red")

vdm <- function(x,n) outer( x, seq(0,n-1), "^" )

fitted <- function (n) { function(xtrain,ytrain) { w <- qr.solve(vdm(xtrain,n), ytrain) 
                                                   function (x) {  vdm(x,n) %*% w} } }


funs2 <- lapply(seq_len(5), function(n) {fitted(n)})          #does not work
funs3 <- lapply(seq_len(5), function(n) {print(n);fitted(n)}) #works
funs4 <- lapply(seq_len(5), fitted )                          #does not work

lapply(funs3, function(f) {ffitted <- f(x10,y10)
                           curve(ffitted,0,1,col="black", add=TRUE)})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you mean. Is the issue that the value of `n` is not what you expect when `fitted` is evaluated? It might help if you precisely explained what you expect, and exactly what is wrong.

Comment: ok I will add some explanation

Comment: I'm still a little unsure what your expected output is, but my guess is that you're seeing lazy evaluation. The `n` isn't evaluated until it's actually needed. In the case of `funs3`, your print call forces the evaluation of `n`. You could probably achieve the same effect by doing `force(n);fitted(n)`.

Comment: +1 to joran, but your code looks like you tried to squeeze in as many (anonymous) functions as possible. As a result it's very difficult to understand.

Comment: `aaply(x10,1,fnoisy)` in place of `fnoisy(x10)` is bordering on the pathological, IMO.

Comment: looks like it, but I don't see where I would rely on side effect here.

Comment: @HongOoi rnom() is defintely side effectful => I want to take 10 independant sample, not 1 applied to each entry.

Comment: Um. 10 consecutive calls to `rnorm(1)` will get you _exactly the same numbers_ as `rnorm(10)`, for a given starting random seed.

Comment: That means you should use `fnoisy <- function (x) {f(x) + 0.3*rnorm(length(x)}`. And why don't you use the `sd` parameter of `rnorm` instead of multiplying with 0.3? That would make the code better to understand.

Comment: @Roland got it. Most mathematical and statistical functions in R are vectorised. You can get N independent random numbers faster and more easily with a single function call than with N function calls.

Comment: @HongOoi yes, so you'd advocate to use fnoisy <- function (x) {f(x) + 0.3*rnorm(length(x))}. now i get you.

Comment: ah, posts crossed. yes that is better, well noted.

Comment: @nicolas Functional programming doesn't mean that `function` needs to be in your code as often as possible. `y10 <- f(x) + rnorm(length(x),sd=0.3)` is perfectly okay.

Comment: @James that looks exactly like it. I wonder what its the cleanest way to get back normal function application semantic.

Comment: closures strikes back. force() seems the best option to me.